# Change button background colour

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-listener

I'm currently trying to complete a quiz page on European countries.

When the button is clicked I would like its background to change to red if wrong or green if right.

My JavaScript isn't working and I'm not sure why. Could anyone give me an alternative or tell me where I have gone wrong?

The way I had planned it logically was, when the button is clicked, turn red if wrong and green if right, then stay that way while the rest of the quiz is being completed.

```js
var A1btn = document.querySelector("#A1btn")

function changeA1BG() {
  A1btn.style.background = "green"
}

A1btn.addEventListener("click", changeA1BG)
```

```css
#QuizBod {
  background-color: #ffff80;
}

#QTitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30pt;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFBF00;
}

#a {
  height: 240px;
  float: left;
  width: 665px;
  background: #FFDCDC;
}

#b {
  background: #F4FFDC;
  height: 240px;
  float: left;
  width: 665px;
}

#c {
  background: #DCFFF7;
  clear: left;
  height: 240px;
  float: left;
  width: 665px;
}

#d {
  background: #EADCFF;
  height: 240px;
  float: left;
  width: 665px;
}

#GeoPic {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100px;
}

.A1btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17.5pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.A2btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17.5pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.A3btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17.5pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.A4btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17.5pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.A5btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17.5pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.A6btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17.5pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.A7btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17.5pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.A8btn {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 17.5pt;
  font-family: 'Langar', cursive;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!--Mobile Compatibility-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!--Style Sheet, Google Font Link, Page Title-->

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Site.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Langar&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Europe Quiz</title>
</head>

<body id="QuizBod">
  <h2 id="QTitle">Europe Country Quiz</h2>

  <div id="a">
    <img id="GeoPic" src="C:\Users\rache\OneDrive - Ulster University\Year 2\COM414 Int Tech\Assessment 2\Site\Images\France.png">
    <p> </p>
    <button class="A1btn">France</button>
    <p> </p>
    <button class="A2btn">Spain</button>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <img id="GeoPic" src="C:\Users\rache\OneDrive - Ulster University\Year 2\COM414 Int Tech\Assessment 2\Site\Images\Germany.png">
    <p> </p>
    <button class="A3btn">Italy</button>
    <p> </p>
    <button class="A4btn">Germany</button>
  </div>
  <div id="c">
    <img id="GeoPic" src="C:\Users\rache\OneDrive - Ulster University\Year 2\COM414 Int Tech\Assessment 2\Site\Images\Ireland.png">
    <p> </p>
    <button class="A5btn">Ireland</button>
    <p> </p>
    <button class="A6btn">Portugal</button>
  </div>
  <div id="d">
    <img id="GeoPic" src="C:\Users\rache\OneDrive - Ulster University\Year 2\COM414 Int Tech\Assessment 2\Site\Images\UK.png">
    <p> </p>
    <button class="A7btn">Russia</button>
    <p> </p>
    <button class="A8btn">UK</button>
  </div>

  <script src="GeogQuiz.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: The actual problem is simply a typo. Your a1btn has a class not id, so `querySelector(".A1btn")` instead of #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `querySelector`, you are calling an id and not class. Your button is a class.

Your code:

```
document.querySelector("#A1btn")
```

What it should be:

```
document.querySelector(".A1btn")
```

Your button:

```
<button class="A1btn">France</button>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I see my problem now :)

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting the element by id but only assigned a class to the element

Try:
`var A1btn = document.querySelector(".A1btn")`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I see my problem now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query selector (`var A1btn = document.querySelector("#A1btn")`) is looking for an element with an *id* of `A1btn`. However, the button in your HTML only has a *class* selector on it.

Use `var A1btn = document.querySelector(".A1btn")`.

---

Additionally, you're using `background-color` in the `.A1btn` style, while you're setting `background` to green via javascript. That might be causing a collision depending on the browser.